# форма из views.py не сохраняет значение введенное пользователем

Tags: python, django, sqlite

В бд сохраняются все значения введенные из форм страницы pat.html
Но суть в том, что бы при вводе данных из этих 2х форм form.Ticket и form.param передавались в следующий скрипт, который лезет в бд, подключается к ней с помощью psycopg2 и менял данные уже в подлюченной базе (сам скрипт изменения в бд на pg рабочий, не передаются эти параметры именно в следующий скрипт, ложится только во внутреннюю бд на sqlite

```
def pat(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Ticket = request.POST['Ticket']
            param = request.POST['param']
            form.save()
            return redirect('pat')
        else:
            error = 'Номер заявки и заявления не должны быть строкой (тип int)'

    form = PatForms()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/pat.html', context,)
```

Вопрос не в скрипте что стоит в фоне, а как получить и использовать значения, которые передавались в форму на сайте и как их корректно передавать в рамках одного проекта.
Скрипт в который должен передавать значения из формы, кусок:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from ..views import pat
# Данные которые будут вытащены из параметра, вводных формы
Ticket = pat(request='Ticket')
param = pat(request='param')
```

Comment: Очень сложно понять, что вами написано, желательно переписать некоторые предложения. Все введенные в форму данные передаются в request.POST. Вы можете оттуда их извлекать и сохранять где вам нужно. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как вывести эти данные хотя бы на консоль.
Не совсем понимаю как присвоить переменную, что бы она перезаписывалась данными с формы в которую ввожу значения и в этот же момент передавать эти значения стороннему скрипту

Comment: `print(request.POST)` выведет все что пришло в post в консоль

Comment: Спасибо, выводит корректно)
Но легче не стало, основной вопрос как этот реквест затолкать в переменные, для передачи в скрипт что лежит в другой папке
Сейчас выглядит так: (на консоль выводит все ок, спасибо)
п.с. поправил в теле вопроса

Comment: Могу ли я как-то с Вами связаться? 
Уже очень долго сижу с этой проблемой, не могу понять в чем дело и даже по человечески описать затрудняюсь, т.к. не понимаю что там происходит. Нужно добиться лишь передачи этих переменных в следующий скрипт, что бы он выполнялся.

Comment: @clickname - tg